# When I enter the text in UITextField the position of whole view moves up

Tags: swift, view, nslayoutconstraint

When I enter the text in UITextfield which is a subview of a subview of the view whole view moves a little bit up.

Class is a view. It has two subviews which are a collectionView and view with its own subview - UITextfield.

I'm creating an object from that class in ViewController and setting up its contraints directly there. Constraints of the rest of components (collectionView and view with textfield) are set up in the class.

When I use panGesture and drag the view to animate UI it works fine. But when the text is entered into textfield it looks like layout is recalculated and bottom constraint gets lower value that desired one.

There is a gif which shows how the problem looks like:
https://gfycat.com/ColorlessTheseAnophelesmosquito

```
@objc func draggedView(_ sender:UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

    ViewController().view.bringSubviewToFront(self)
    let translation = sender.translation(in: ViewController().view)

    if self.layer.frame.minY >= UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 0.25 && translation.y > 0 {


        //values
        self.bottomTaskViewConstraint.constant = -30
        self.heightTaskViewContraint.constant = 55

        //animation
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) {

            self.pinPosition = UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 0.33
            self.layer.frame.origin.y = self.pinPosition
            self.visibleHeight = ViewController().view.frame.maxY - self.frame.maxY - 20
            self.bottomConstraint.constant = self.visibleHeight
            self.layoutIfNeeded()


        }

        self.newTaskTextfield.becomeFirstResponder()

    } else if self.layer.frame.minY <= UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 0.33 && self.layer.frame.minY > UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 0.25 && translation.y < 0 {

        //values
        self.bottomTaskViewConstraint.constant = -100
        self.heightTaskViewContraint.constant = 110

        //animation
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) {

            self.pinPosition = UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 0.25
            self.layer.frame.origin.y = self.pinPosition
            self.visibleHeight = ViewController().view.frame.maxY - self.frame.maxY - 20
            self.bottomConstraint.constant = self.visibleHeight
            self.layoutIfNeeded()

        }

        newTaskTextfield.resignFirstResponder()

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. Solution:
Add self.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false to viewDidLoad() in your ViewController which is a parent of your view class.